# tableviewcell open url on click swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, webview, uitableview

I've been trying to make a url open when I click a cell in my tableview programatticaly without having to make a webview controller and mess with seques. Any help on how I can get this accomplished. Below is the code I've tried

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        NSURL(string: "App Store Link")!
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        NSURL(string: "Send Us Feedback - Contact On Website")!
    }  else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        NSURL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/prs_app/")!
    }  else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        NSURL(string: "Snapchat")!
    }

}
```

I appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com")!)
```

this will open the safari browser for you

edit *explanation for question in comment*
It is better if you'll add enums or other constants, but this will do:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let url : NSURL?

    switch indexPath.section{
    case 0:
        switch indexPath.row{
        case 0:
            url = NSURL(string: "http://section0.row0.com")
        case 1:
            url = NSURL(string: "http://section0.row1.com")
        default:
            return;
        }

    case 1:
        switch indexPath.row{
        case 0:
            url = NSURL(string: "http://section1.row0.com")
        case 1:
            url = NSURL(string: "http://section1.row1.com")
        default:
            return;
        }
    default:
        return;
    }

    if url != nil{
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works, But in the case of changing the url for each cell it only goes to the first link for the cell (0 - apple.com). Is there a way to make each cell go to a different link?

Comment: ' if indexPath.row == 0 {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")!)

   
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")!)
        }  else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.instagram.com/prs_app")!)
        }  else if indexPath.row == 3 {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.snapchat.com")!)
        } '

Comment: well, are you sure you are clicking the right cells? or are you sure you are not confusing with row and sections? because if you have 4 rows on your `UITableView` your code should work (thu there are bit more clear ways to write it)

Comment: I have two sections in my table view.

Comment: @NateGrant ok, then you should also check your `indexPath.section` and not only `indexPath.row`

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. How would I be able to do that in code if you don't mind?

Comment: it gives me an error on the line with 'case 1:' saying "additional case blocks cannot appear after the 'default' block of a switch"

Comment: @NateGrant my bad, fixed

Comment: Awesome it worked! Thank you much! Marked as Answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have other solution for this, hope it works

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
    let link = sectionContent[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].link

    switch indexPath.section {
    // Leave us feedback section
//You can add as many sections you want.

    case 0:
        if let url = URL(string: link) {
            let safariController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
            present(safariController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    // Follow us section
    case 1:
        if let url = URL(string: link) {
            let safariController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
            present(safariController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

     default:
         break
     }

     tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
 }
```